# RegularExpression question for matching a string literal from user input

Tags: java, regex

Here's a little bit of code I wrote for a FileFilter using a regular expression. It's purpose is to match for uploaded log files and increment an index on the file name. I'd like to not have to worry about anything in the filename and just accept it as a string literal without spinning through the filename escaping characters that are meaningful to the regex pattern matching.

mylog.log
mylog-1.log
mylog-2.log

```
        public boolean accept(File file) {
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(filenameWithoutExtension + "-*[0-9]*." + extension);
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(file.getName());
            return matcher.matches();
        }
```

My question is, If the file name contains a parenthesis, This won't work as the parenthetical means something special to the pattern matcher.

mylog(copy).log

I'd like to surround filenameWithoutExtension with a notation that says, match this string ignoring anything in it that might be pattern matching syntax otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Pattern.quote](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29).